# Node object isn't callable. Please resolve

Tags: python

```py
#Linked List

class Node:
    def __init__(self,item):
        self.item = None
        self.next = item

class Linked:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    
    def printlist(self):
        printval = self.head
        while printval is not None:
            printval(printval.item)
            printval = printval.next
    
    def insertion(self,newitem):
        NewNode = Node(newitem)
        NewNode.next = self.head
        self.head = NewNode

    def InsertBetween(self,Middle_Node,newitem):
        if Middle_Node is None:
            print("Value doesn't exist in node")
            return
        NewNode = Node(newitem)
        NewNode.next = Middle_Node.next
        Middle_Node.next = NewNode


listy = Linked()
listy.head = Node(20)
p2 = Node(21)
p3 = Node(22)
listy.head.next = p2
p2.next = p3
listy.InsertBetween(listy.head.next,40)
listy.insertion(45)
listy.printlist()
```

I'm getting this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Tanishq\Desktop\Python Practice SORTS\LList.py", line 41, in <module> 
    listy.printlist()
  File "c:\Users\Tanishq\Desktop\Python Practice SORTS\LList.py", line 15, in printlist
    printval(printval.item)
TypeError: 'Node' object is not callable
```

Comment: What do you expect that `printval(printval.item)` should do? Did you mean: `print(printval.item)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two mistakes in your code:

1. You are setting the variable item to None for every node and next to an int value.

The correct way would be the other way around

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,item):
    self.item = item
    self.next = None
```

2. In printlist there seems to be a typo printval should be print

   `print(printval.item)`

I am assuming you are trying to implement a linked list and the above changes should get you the desired result